# ffmpeg error convertimg mkv to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, avconv, mkv

I do this:

```
 ffmpeg -i "film.mkv" -strict experimental film.mp4
```

I get this:

```
[matroska,webm @ 0x29fb0e0] Read error at pos. 93417 (0x16ce9)
```

the file itself is playable and ok, but how can I fix this? or at least see the reason why it is reporting this, any clues?

Comment: What version of ffmpeg are you using? Can you provide a small sample?

Comment: @aergistal those files that are not converted are having the encode: Lavf55.12.0 - i dont know if this somehow affects it, ffmpeg version 2.6.8